# How to read response from google login api sent as json

Tags: java, google-api, google-signin

I am currently working on google login api. I completed the first step of login and now I have google code sent by api. Now I need user's id or email but I am not able to get it. According to google doc it says

> Google will respond to your POST request by returning a JSON object that contains a short-lived access token and a refresh token.

In point 5 in link.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

I am not able to get this json object. I tried using

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          String line = null;
          try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
              sb.append(line);
          } catch (Exception e) { }
```

> How can I process this kind of response to get this Json object. I followed many blogs, posts but could not find the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is a good library to manage JSON data. You can find a crash-start guide to use Jackson [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).

Comment: Okay but this is applicable when I get data from response. Currently I need to retrieve data send by google api as a reponse.